# Force quantization in physics?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, forces

since we know from classical physics that

$$ \vec F= \frac{d\vec p}{dt} $$

and the quantization of momentum $ \hat p = -i\hbar\nabla $

can we expect that the force in quantum physics should appear as

$$ \hat F_{x_i}= -i\hbar \frac{\partial ^2}{\partial t \partial x_i}$$

for the compoments of the force . :D

Comment: See [Ehrenfest theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ehrenfest_theorem).

Comment: In QM you use Hamiltonian formalism so you don't really need to deal with the forces as they are encapsulated in potential term. If I had to  guess, you could maybe define force as expectation value of $-\frac{\partial V}{\partial x}$, but I'm not sure if there is straightforward connection of force with momentum in QM.

Comment: Why would a "force" appear in quantum physics at all? What are you trying to do here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, let us see heuristically!
$$
\hat{F}=-i\hbar\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\nabla
$$
On the other hand, let us assume we are dealing with a conservative force field
$$
F=-\nabla V
$$
Now to equate these two, we need the second $F$ to be an operator. We are thus faced with the question of giving an *operatorial definition* for potentials. This is not a settled textbook dogma and people, following [Vaidman's](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevA.86.040101) maxim, are trying to do this; see for example *[here](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevA.95.052124)*; the issue is still open --Vaidman told me-- as of last year. Being short of any clue for operatorial definition of $V$ let us just proceed with the simplest possibility
$$
\hat{F}\psi \stackrel{?}{=}-(\nabla V)\psi
$$
yielding
$$
i\hbar\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\nabla\psi\stackrel{?}{=}(\nabla V)\psi;
$$
seems like a dead-end to me. *But* let us take
$$
\hat{F}\psi :=-\nabla (V\psi),
$$
then
$$
i\hbar\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\nabla\psi=\nabla (V\psi),
$$
as time and position(s) variables are independent, they commute on the left-hand-side --Uncertainty principle buzzers be calm, in your terms I am commuting energy and momentum, which is fine-- therefore
$$
i\hbar\nabla\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\psi=\nabla (V\psi),
$$
it *seems* we can 'cancel' nablas from both sides but this is a subtle issue outside the scope of this answer; I have explored it in detail [here](https://vixra.org/abs/2004.0677). Let us *assume for the moment* that we can do this, so
$$
i\hbar\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\psi=V\psi,
$$
which must immediately ring a bell: it is *part* of the Schrödinger equation. So what has gone wrong?
I found out it [turns out](https://vixra.org/abs/2004.0677) that the `right way' (in the sense of leading to Schrödinger equation) to deal with the Newton Second Law in quantum mechanics is to see momentum as a *function of trajectory and time*, i.e.
$$
\textbf{p}=\textbf{p}\big(\textbf{x}(t),t\big)
$$
and proceed with the chain rule.

Comment: PS. The answers so far are not to the point. I trust there should be some point in having a good will and some `faith' thinking about someone's question who decided to bring it to public.

Answer (score 4):

Stick to one space dimension, as you appear conflicted about the vector structure involved. In the Heisenberg picture,
$$
\hat F = \frac{d\hat p}{dt} =\frac{1}{i\hbar} [\hat p, \hat H]\\
=\frac{1}{i\hbar} [\hat p,V(\hat x)]= -V'(\hat x),
$$
which is what you apply in the Ehrenfest theorem, as stressed in the comments.

To generalize to more dimensions, you vectorize both the left hand side, and the right hand side, utilizing $\nabla$ instead of  $~~'\equiv\partial_x$.

Your gradient representation of $\hat p$ is *strictly* in the  coordinate representation, $\hat p=-i\hbar \int\! dx ~|x\rangle \partial_x \langle x|$, which you *need not* stick to. The above expression is valid in any and all representations!

In the coordinate representation, then, the above commutator presents trivially, $-[\partial_x, V(x)]= -V'(x)$. As almost always, time and space partial derivatives act dramatically differently in Hilbert space...